# Azure AD JWT token: how to see through which client secret it was granted

Tags: oauth-2.0, jwt, azure-active-directory, payload

I have an Azure AD application and have generated two client secrets. I can get a JWT access token using each secret (via `client_credentials` grant) but can I also see from the JWT token via which client secret it was requested?

If I inspect the JWT tokens I get back, some payload fields are always the same (`aud`, `iss`, etc) and some are always different (`iat`, `nbf`, `aio`, etc) but there is no info as far as I can tell that identifies the client secret that was used.

Here's an example payload:

```
{
  "aud": "https://graph.microsoft.com",
  "iss": "https://sts.windows.net/e402c5fb-58e9-48c3-b567-741c4cef0b96/",
  "iat": 1516886787,
  "nbf": 1516886787,
  "exp": 1516890687,
  "aio": "Y2NgYEjJqF0stqv73u41a6ZmxPEvBgA=",
  "app_displayname": "TravelAgencies",
  "appid": "ee8cf944-bf6f-42cf-ae30-6060412416a1",
  "appidacr": "2",
  "e_exp": 262800,
  "idp": "https://sts.windows.net/e402c5fb-58e9-48c3-b567-741c4cef0b96/",
  "oid": "bc430bc6-d9fb-4fa0-87e5-8b8803fcb222",
  "sub": "bc430bc6-d9fb-4fa0-87e5-8b8803fcb222",
  "tid": "e402c5fb-58e9-48c3-b567-741c4cef0b96",
  "uti": "1TgusyfGtECjErT0Kv4PAA",
  "ver": "1.0"
}
```

On a related note: what are the `aio`, `e_exp` and `uti` fields for? I can't find any information on them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't see through which client secret has the token been issued. What is the reason for asking through which secret it was?

Regarding provided claims - you can check [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-token-and-claims) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-protocols-oauth-code) what the different claims mean. For exampe the `iat`, `nbf` are just dates - when the token was issued and the validity begin time.

For some of the claims, like `aio` there is no documentation. But there is no claim to show you which secret was used.

Comment: My idea was to have one AD app and to provide each customer his / her own secret, assuming I could derive customer identity from the JWT. But I think it's a better idea to have a separate AD app per customer.

Answer (score 3):

From https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/id-tokens

`aio` An internal claim used by Azure AD to record data for token reuse. Should be ignored.